# The value of $y$ when $x=1+2^p ,y=1+2^{-p}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $$x=1+2^p ,y=1+2^{-p}$$

Then what is $y$ equal to ?

Comment: You want $y$ with the respect to what?

Comment: with the respect to  $x$

Comment: $x-1=2^p$, $y-1=2^{-p}$. Multiply.

Answer (score 3):

$$ x - 1 = 2^p$$
$$\frac{1}{x-1} = 2^{-p}$$
$$y = 1+ \frac{1}{x-1}$$ 
for $x \ne 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want $y$ with respect to $x$, note that $$2^{-p}=\frac{1}{2^p}.$$ Can you rewrite $2^p$ in terms of $x$?